# Rails 3.2 with Devise: logout link stopped working

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

The log out link in my app has been working fine, then it just stopped working. I haven't tested it for a while, but I haven't made any changes to anything related to it for a month! It is sending a `GET` request when it should be interpreted by the controller as a `DELETE` request. Here is my code:

My ERB file in my view includes this line:

```
<li><%= link_to('Log Out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete)%></li>
```

and also includes this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

This is from my `application.js`:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require jquery.serializeJSON
//= require jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom
//= require jquery-ui-touchpunch.min.js
//= require auto_form_bot
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_tree .
```

And here is the pertinent stuff from my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'backbone-on-rails', '~> 1.1'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'devise', '>= 3.1.0'
gem 'ejs'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
```

This is the actual html that is rendered:

```
<li><a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Log Out</a></li>
```

When I click on the link, here is the error I get:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

And here is my server log:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-19 23:49:24 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out")
```

Here are the relevant routes:

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)     devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)     devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)    devise/sessions#destroy
```

The `GET` request generated by the link should automatically be changed to a `DELETE` request, but it isn't anymore, and I don't know what I changed to make it stop working.

Even stranger, every once in a while it actually works! And the same link works on another page in my app.  Here is a link to the demo account of my app, where you will be logged in automatically, so you can log out: http://www.form-itable.com/accounts/demo

I can't figure out what I am missing here. I know I can make a workaround, but the link should work and worked fine until now, and I want to know why it isn't.

Comment: there should be `POST` request not `DELETE` or `GET`, because some browsers don`t support `DELETE` method

Comment: @hawk, you are correct, but because it is a link, it only does `GET`, but it should be automatically changed to `DELETE` because of the `data-method="delete"` part. It works elsewhere in my app.

Comment: Rails will expand `method: :delete` to something like this `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />` then only after this your server should threat your request as `DELETE` request not browser.

Comment: I think something wrong with your javascript part check `jquery_ujs` is loading as expected on every page, and `document.ready` event is triggered on each page

Comment: Yeah, seems like rails.js is not called after the page load. **handleMethod** is the method that will change the get method to delete. Alternatively you can change `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `config.sign_out_via = :get` in devise.rb to get the things working.

Comment: How can I check if jquery_ujs is functioning properly? The code for it is definitely being loaded onto the page. `document.ready` is definitely working, I have a lot of code that depends on that.

Comment: @hawk, and Ishank Gupta, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! It was an issue with jquery_ujs.  jquery_ujs was running fine, but I accidentally turned off it's click event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was reading through the [jquery_ujs files](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) I saw that it appears that it turns links from `GET` to `DELETE` by setting up an event listener on the `document`, like so:

```
// Link elements bound by jquery-ujs
linkClickSelector: 'a[data-confirm], a[data-method], a[data-remote], a[data-disable-with]'
```

...

```
$document.delegate(rails.linkClickSelector, 'click.rails', function(e) {
  var link = $(this), method = link.data('method'), data = link.data('params'), metaClick = e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey;
... more code ...
```

In my app at one point, I had a complicated situation where I needed to remove a `click` event from the `document`, and since I wasn't using any other click handlers, I just called `$(document).off('click');` which removes everything that is listening to click events on the `document`. This, apparently, is a very bad thing. I replaced that line with something that specifically removed my click handler, and everything works again.

The lesson is that if you are using jQuery_ujs **do not ever use `off()` on the `document` unless you can target a specific handler**.