# destroy_user_session_path is triggering GET instead of DELETE in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my view:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
```

Which generates the following HTML:

```
<a data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a>
```

However, when clicking on that link, I get the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is it doing a GET instead of DELETE?

I am using Twitter Bootstrap if that helps...

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Make sure you have: <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %> in your head tag

Comment: Replace `:defaults` in the previous comment with `:application` in Rails 3.1 and above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs
```

in your application.js file?

An alternative monkey patch would be to modify the devise.rb and change the signout method to get
like so

config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

This post may shed some light:
[Rails 3.2 with Devise: logout link stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698511/rails-3-2-with-devise-logout-link-stopped-working)

Comment: The alternate monkey patch is not a good idea - if the asker's JS isn't set up correctly, no delete links will work across the entire site.

Comment: totally agree with you

Comment: @emcanes just curious to know how do you know he is using devise .

Comment: @paritosh - just an assumption as he is mentioning standard devise path names, destroy routes, etc. that are all exactly what devise uses. The link_to method is character for character exactly from their github account and I have seen it hundreds of times.  So it is possibly he isn't using it for sure but my hunch is he probably is.  Also the solution I posted with checking the application.js for those files relates to how the delete links are handled and the failback to a get method if they arent included.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two points to get rid of this error:

1. In your `routes.rb` (if you don't want to use `:delete` method):

   `devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end`
2. `sign_out` link must have to contain `:method => :delete` (already you have)

   `<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>`

   And finally, in your `layout` put:

   `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`link_to` [fails back to a get if Javascript is not enabled](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). Looks like either your browser has Javascript disabled or more likely there is a Javascript error on the page. If there is an uncaught Javascript error on your page all other Javascript will fail to run after the error occurs.