# Why does this link_to use GET rather than DELETE like I specified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using `devise`, and this is my link:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method: :delete, class: "dropdown-item" %>
```

This is the output of the logs when I click the link:

```
Started GET "/logout" for ::1 at 2020-04-16 21:24:58 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/logout"):
```

This is the HTML it generates:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Logout</a>
```

This is the relevant section of my `routes.rb`:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    delete "logout", to: "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end
```

Comment: any javascript errors in console? Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004078/4414956 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465919/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails' link\_to method: GETing when it should DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465919/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete)

Comment: The reason its being sent as a GET request is that something is preventing the event listener declared by Rails UJS from working. This could be that your application.js is missing `require("@rails/ujs").start()` or a script error. Without that event listener its just a plain old link and browsers handle clicks on links by sending a GET request. For something as critical as a log out button I would consider hardening your app by using `button_to` instead which works even if javascript is turned off completely.

Comment: @max sorry for the delayed reply, but your suggestion about using `button_to` worked like a charm. The other links weren't very helpful but that `button_to` suggestion was perfect. Thanks! If you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Could be written as well as `require("rails-ujs").start()` depending on how you import it, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @max's comment on my question above:

> The reason its being sent as a GET request is that something is
> preventing the event listener declared by Rails UJS from working. This
> could be that your application.js is missing
> `require("@rails/ujs").start()` or a script error. Without that event
> listener its just a plain old link and browsers handle clicks on links
> by sending a GET request. For something as critical as a log out
> button I would consider hardening your app by using button_to instead
> which works even if javascript is turned off completely.

So I changed the `link_to` to `button_to` and that worked like a charm.